# Using a try block as an expected part of the program flow

Tags: vb.net

I'm parsing some data into a dictionary. Some keys might repeat and should overwrite existing data so I had to check if the dictionary contained the key or not but then I got this idea:

instead of

```
        If Dict.ContainsKey(key) Then
            Dict(key) = val
        Else
            Dict.Add(key, val)
        End If
```

I used this

```
        Try
            Dict(key) = val
        Catch ex As Exception
            Dict.Add(key, val)
        End Try
```

I did some benchmarking, added 100k random keys in the range of 0 - 1k in a dictionary the size of 1k. The version using the try/catch block seems to be consistently 40% faster in release build mode.

Now from my understanding about the Dictionary object, its not just a hash table since a pure hash table would have no clue what keys are used and since I only need the hash table functionality, passing this artificial constraint seems no harm to me.

What troubles me a little is the use of try block to achieve this, isn't it supposed to be reserved for actual exceptions in program flow?

Comment: If the catch is never executed because there are no duplicates the try-catch is more efficient, of course. But 40% of nearly nothing is still nearly nothing. So is there really a performance issue? Also, what type is the key?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<s>All depends on the number of duplicate keys. If there are none the catch is not executed.</s>

But you don't need to check it. If you use:

```
Dict(key) = val
```

it will add new key or overwrite existing.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/9tee9ht2(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: The catch block is *never* executed in case of duplicite keys; because when using the indexer instead of `Add`, existing keys get overwritten. You even say this yourself in your answer :-)

Comment: @DangeMasK: i've edited your answer since you have provided the wrong link. I hope it's ok.

Comment: @TimSchmelter Thanks, I'm still new to posting answers here, so I appreciate any help :-)

Comment: oh it appears you're right. Somehow I remember getting errors for trying to set a key that didn't exist...